# how to upload image in custom from in magento 2.4

Tags: image, magento2.4, contact-form, custom-field

How to upload image array in custom from in Magento 2.4

```
                <div class="file-item-container mb-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="field files mb-3">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <label for="files" class="label cw-green-color">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Upload Images (Max file size: 5mb)')) ?></label>
                                    <input name="files[]" id="files"
                                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($viewModel->getUserName()) ?>"
                                           class="input-text form-control" type="file"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please check updated answer and Update me.

Answer (score 0):

> **phtml form be like this**

```
<form class="form"
      name="inquiryFrom"
      action="productinquiry/productinquiry/save"
      id="inq-form"
      method="post"
      enctype='multipart/form-data'
      autocomplete="off"
      >
      <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div id="file-upload-section" class="field file">
          <label class="label" for="inquiry_msg">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Upload File:') ?></span>
          </label>
          <div class="control">
            <input id="attachment-file"
                   class="attachment-file"
                   name="attachment[]"
                   type="file"
                   multiple="multiple" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
          <button type="submit"
                  id="inq-submit"
                  class="action submit primary "
                  title="<?= $block->escapeHtml('Submit') ?>" >
              <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Submit') ?></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

> **For Save Image**

```
protected $fileSystem;

protected $uploaderFactory;


public function __construct(
    .............................................
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    .............................................
) {
    .............................................
    $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    .............................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    // attechmengt save
    $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('attachment');
    $length = count($filesData);
    $file_store = '';
    try {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            if ($filesData[$i]['error'] == 0) {
                $field_name = "attachment[" . $i . "]";
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(["fileId" => $field_name]);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('tmp/attachment');
                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
                if (!$result) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                    );
                }
                $file_store .= $result['file'] . ",";
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Attachment not Uplaoded, Please try Agrain'));
    }
    $data['attachment'] = $file_store;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data)
    exit();

    .....................................
    .....................................
}
```